# How to convert from a non nullable column to a nullable in WP7 and SQLCE

Tags: windows-phone-7, migration, sql-server-ce

I built the first version of my app with the following column on a table:

```
private int _photo;
[Column]
public int photo { get; set;}
```

Now with the second version of the app, I changed the type of photo from int to a nullable int?

Is there any way to make the DB update?? If there is not how do you exactly migrate data? I've seen that you can do it but never how you can do it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11129931/434034), it also handles how to handle the update.

Comment: raw sql queries are not supported in WP/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570959/update-linqtosql-database-with-new-schema-changes/8571273#8571273

Comment: i was trying to change the scheme to update a column type. I gave up since there is no way through the framework to do it in WP7